# Is there a vi file editor in ubuntu like in unix?

Tags: executable, chmod, vi

I was a unix and redhat user, just started to use ubuntu. Is there a vi command to edit files? Is there a change mode command to change a file status to executable?

Comment: It would be better to ask two different questions.

Comment: Why did you think to come ask such a question instead of simply trying it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `vi` in Ubuntu as well:

```
vi file.txt
```

To make a file excecutable use

```
sudo chmod u+x file.foo
```

Comment: Most of the time it would be better to `chmod u+x file.foo` *without* invoking sudo. In fact, I think you'd only need sudo if you don't own the file. It's also possible to call chmod within `vi` -- while in normal mode, type `:!chmod u+x %` and then press enter to change the permissions on the current file.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the commands are identical
vi (or vim = vi iMproved)  is invoked by entering **vi** in the command line and 
**chmod** changes can be used to change a file's executable flag exactly as in Redhat...

Comment: Where is the command line? How do I open a window that prompts me to enter a command like vi or chmod?

Comment: From a unity desktop, do ctrl, alt t to open up a new shell, then you can vi to your hearts content.

Comment: @JingWang be warned that vi/vim has a bit of a learning curve. If you're new to using the command-line, I'd recommend using `nano` (if you want a CLI-based editor) or even gedit (the default Ubuntu GUI text-editor).